# Error Propagation When "Finding" a Value in an Array (using np.where for example)

Tags: error, error-propagation

Consider you are given a dataset with `x`, `y` and `y_err` where `y_err` is the 1-sigma error you computed for `y`. You don't have errors for `x`. `y(x)` is a function that is decreasing and assume it has no analytical form. Now assume you want to find for which x value, y is equal to a target value (i.e find x(y_target)). This is easy using numpy but I am not sure how to propagate the errors. Do I just find the min and max `x_target` values for `y + y_err` and `y - y_err` and call that the 1-sigma range of `x_target`?

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example of the steps (in this case the target y value is 0.4):

```
# given 
x_input, y_input, y_input_err 

# algo
f = interp1d(x_input, y_input)
x = np.arange(x_input.min(), x_input.max(), .0001)
y = f(x)

target_y = 0.4
min_idx = np.argmin(abs(y - target_y))
target_x = x[min_idx] 

# plot
plt.errorbar(x_input, y_input, yerr=y_input_err, marker='o', c='black', label='Data')
plt.fill_between(x_input, y_input - y_input_err, y_input + y_input_err, alpha=0.1, color='black')
plt.plot(x, y, c='r', label='interp1d')

plt.axvline(target_x, label='X(0.4) = {}'.format(target_x))
plt.axhline(target_y)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
```

[image]